# How to add button in html table and create event using asp.net and C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I wanted to add button in the html table column from the C#. I have attached the code behind and asp.net in the code.button is creating in the column for each row but not calling to the click event.

```
        public string getWhileLoopData()
    {
        string htmlStr = "";

        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Id,EmployeeEmail,PayReference from EmployeeDetails";
        thisConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

        PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            long id = reader.GetInt64(0);
            string Name = reader.GetString(1);
            string Pass = reader.GetString(2);[enter image description here][1]
            htmlStr += "<tr class='row_data'><th data-employee-id='" + id + "'>" + id + "</th><th>" + Name + "</th><th>" + Pass + "</th><th>  <input id='Button1' runat='server' class='button right' onserverclick='Button1_Click' type='submit' value='Update' /> </th></tr>";
        }

        thisConnection.Close();
        return htmlStr;
    }
```

ASP.NET code is below

```
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead align="left" style="background-color: #004080; color: White;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email Address
                </th>
                <th>
                    Empr Paye Ref.
                </th>
                <th>
                    Open
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%=getWhileLoopData()%>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: with raw data in c# you will be able to raise javascript events not server postbacks. you will need control like repeater that supports template where you can specifiy click event. by the way , you can also do manually postback with javascript

Comment: Just curious why not use ASP.net grid or list view control for this ?

Comment: I want to use HTML table and JQuery for Paging and Searching and my code is fit for responsive with grid.

Answer (score 0):

There's no event called `onserverclick`.
You can use asp button instead of html button and use `onclick` event.